# Why does Google have a class B IP address?

Tags: ip, ip-address

Google has an IP address of `142.250.64.206`. I found this out using `nslookup`.

Why is it class B and not class A? Isn't Google a huge network?

Answer (score -1):

The whole A, B, C class system was obsoleted decades ago with the introduction of [Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) (CIDR).  https://www.findip-address.com/ shows 142.250.64.206 is part of a /24 CIDR block, not a /16 as the class B would've indicated (years ago).

Schools still teach this though, and I am not sure why.  But you *should* know that when someone gives you an address and also says "it's a class C mask" or simply (and, technically, incorrectly) "it's a class C", the mask is /24.  That's the only time in comes up in the real world.